# Join two table with specific conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two table

**Table 1:** (user) id,name,username,password

**table 2:** (order) id,user,status

**status** **column** have two value: 1(cancel order) **or** 2(success order)

I want show **all user** list with order count as **orders** (order count for only success order)

I write this sql :

```
  select `user`.* , count(`sale`.`user`) as 'orders'
  from `user` 
  left join `sale`
      on `sale`.`user` = `user`.`id`
  where `user`.`type` = 'customer'
    and (`sale`.`status` IS NULL OR `sale`.`status` = 2)
  group by `user`.`id`
  order by `user`.`id` DESC
```

in this query if user not have any order or have success order is showing in result

**but if user have canceled order is not show in result**

I want show **all user** in result with orders column

If order status is 2, order column show count of success order

If order status is 1 or null (user not have any order) in order column of result show 0 count

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Some sample table data and the expected result would be great! (As formatted text, no images.) https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the condition on `status` to the `on` clause:

```
  select u.* , count(s.user) as orders
  from `user` u left join
       sale s
        on s.`user` = u.id AND s.status = 2
  where u.`type` = 'customer'
  group by u.id  -- ok, assuming id is unique
  order by u.id  DESC
```